# Drawing Rectangles on an image from a different class

Tags: c#, class, graphics

I am attempting to generate a set of rectangles on an image. To achieve this, I call a method that is present in a seperate class (Because multiple forms need to call this function.) Let's say I have Form A and Form B that both need to draw said set of rectangles:

From Form A it works just fine, from Form B it doesn't draw anything, but it doesn't return an exception either.

To make sure I haven't missed anything, I went as far as to copy and paste the function calls from both forms so the two of them are identical. I have also triple checked any semantic errors but have been unable to find any.

The function call from Form A is as follows:

```
 private void PbPreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (NewPage) //This bool is true when the user is displaying a new page(Image)
     {
         StartingY = MousePosition.Y - 76; //Save the Y position of the click in a float variable
         Form1.MainController.DrawRect(StartingY, PbPreview.Image); //Function call
         NewPage = false; //Set the new Page bool to false to prevent overdrawing
     }
 }
```

The function call from Form B is as follows:

```
 private void PbFactuur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (NewPage) //Same use as the NewPage bool from above
     {
         MouseY = MousePosition.Y - 76; //Saving mouse position
         Form1.MainController.DrawRect(MouseY, PbFactuur.Image); //Function call
         NewPage = false; //Set new page to false to prevent overdrawing
         MessageBox.Show("I have executed the function"); //Debug info
     }
 }
```

And here is the code that is present within the function:

```
 public void DrawRect(float Ypos, Image DrawSubject)
 {
     try
     {
         foreach (Rectangle R in Form1.nieuwBedrijf.Rects)
         {
             Rectangle TempRect = R;
             TempRect.Y = Convert.ToInt32(Ypos);
             Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(DrawSubject);
             G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, TempRect.X * Form1.nieuwBedrijf.ScaleX, TempRect.Y * Form1.nieuwBedrijf.ScaleY, TempRect.Width * Form1.nieuwBedrijf.ScaleX, 1920);
         }
     }
     catch
     {
          MessageBox.Show("No rectangles have been defined yet.");
     }
 }
```

Sidenote: Rects is a list of user defined rectangles.

The expected result would be that at the location where the user clicks, the set of rectangles will appear. But in reality, nothing appears at all.

The application doesn't return any sort of error message, and with the use of breakpoints and messageboxes I have been able to verify that the function does execute.

I hope anyone is able to point me to a potential solution to this problem.

Many thanks in advance
~Melvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering around I have found the following solution:

The rectangles were actually being drawn, but it was not being shown on screen. To have the rectangles show up on screen, I had to add the following line of code:

```
private void PbFactuur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (NewPage) //Same use as the NewPage bool from above
     {
         MouseY = MousePosition.Y - 76; //Saving mouse position
         Form1.MainController.DrawRect(MouseY, PbFactuur.Image); //Function call
         NewPage = false; //Set new page to false to prevent overdrawing
         MessageBox.Show("I have executed the function"); //Debug info
         Refresh();//<----- This line fixed the problem
     }
 }
```